# WebClient download - how to detech bad URL

Tags: .net, vb.net, url, webclient

We recently started playing with a vb.net 2008 WebClient on a Windows 7/64 workstation to download files from a web site to the local machine.

It works except that we cannot detect if the URL is invalid.  It doesn't throw an error.  If we use Async it does trigger the Download Complete event but there was no file since the URL was incorrect.

Is there a way to detect an incorrect URL?

I also noticed that the events does not give you either the URL or the file?  It seems like it should?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear what you mean by invalid url. It could mean 2 things:

1. Not properly formatted url
2. Properly formatted url but the server doesn't respond with HTTP 2xx or 3xx status code

As far as detecting a properly formatted url is concerned you could use the [`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx) method before attempting to send an HTTP request. And as far as detecting the second condition is concerned, well, you cannot detect it until you actually send an HTTP request to the given url. If the server responds with a status code that is different than 2xx or 3xx such as for example 404 or 500 an exception will be thrown that you can catch. And if you are using the async versions of the methods no exception will be thrown but in the complete callback you have to check if the `Error` property of the passed EventArgs instance is not null before attempting to access the `Result` property.

Comment: I am interested in the 2nd.  Bad URL i.e. File not found.  How do you get the the response.

Comment: @QuickBooksDev, there are many possibilities. The server sends a 404 HTTP status code => 2 possibilities: 1. you are using asynchronous API - in this case you test the Error property of the EventArgs passed in the complete callback and 2. you are using the synchronous API - an exception is thrown. The second case is that the server doesn't send 404 status code but just 200 status code with an error page. In this case you will have to basically parse the returned HTML to know whether it contains an error message or not. Very difficult to distinguish between the actual success case.

Comment: Try catch does not spring in either async or sync. Download complete has nothing in e.error

Comment: @QuickBooksDev, so you fall in the case where the server sends status code 200 even for not found pages. You will have to parse the returned HTML to identify this case as there's nothing that would allow you to disambiguate between the success and the error condition. If the server doesn't respect the HTTP protocol and REST standards, consuming clients will suffer.

Comment: As far as I know nothing is being returned. Can you please tell me how to get the response HTML.  I am not sure what standards you are talking about.  It is just an exe file in a folder on our web site.

Comment: i have added both a catch ex as exception and ex as webException in a sync request and it never is caught. Falls through each time either with a bad URL - bad domain or bad file name (i.e. not found).   Why is it not trapping the error???

Comment: @QuickBooksDev, because the server doesn't send a proper status code. Even in the case of error the server sends HTTP 200 status code as I have already explained.

Comment: Not seeing a 200 status code either.  For a file not found I am not getting any error.  Nothing being trapped.  But I see what is happening.  We are getting the html 404 page and that is being downloaded instead.